# what does this do, preg_match

Tags: php, cakephp

```
preg_match('/^(AREA|TEST)$/i', $arrow)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

returns `1` if the string (in $arrow) equals `area` or `test`, case-insensitive. Else, it returns `0`

[preg_match](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: It actually returns the number of times the expression was found, but it will always be 0 or 1, because it stops after the first time the expression was found (as opposed to preg_match_all). I know, tomayto, tomahto.

Comment: Also please note that using regular expressions in that case is a huge overuse.

Comment: And that if a third argument is given `, $arrow, $matches)` it will be populated with the match information (array).